# Vert.x POST callback not firing

Tags: java, vert.x, quarkus

What I have:
A simple node server listening on port 8100 for POST requests:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var port = 8100;
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/v1/auth/jwt/login', (req, res) => {
  console.log('Here is the body:');
  console.log(req.body);

  res.json({ message: 'received' });
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`));
```

I can confirm that this logs and return a response correctly. (via PostMan/Insomnia/etc)

What I'm trying to do is hit this with a Vert.x webclient:

```
public void getServiceJwt() {
    String loginJwt = getLoginJwt();
    System.out.println("Initiating request");
    JsonObject payload = new JsonObject()
            .put("role", "some-service")
            .put("jwt", loginJwt);
    client
        .post("/v1/auth/jwt/login")
        .sendJsonObject(payload, ar -> {
            if (ar.succeeded()) {
                System.out.println("things went well");
            } else {
                System.out.println(ar);
                System.out.println("something went horribly wrong");
            }
        });
}
```

The request happens, as I can see the payload data logged. What seems to not happen is the `ar` callback. I don't get a log in either case. It's almost as if the request is not returning... but I have no idea how to check. There is no stack trace, no errors. Just, nothing. This example is pretty much right out of the docs.

I'm at a loss on how to troubleshoot this further.

Comment: Can you make sure with Wireshark that the backend actually replies?

Comment: I'm no Wireshark expert, but it looks like my route handler returns with `204 No Content` before my webclient makes its request. The client request does fire and succeed though, so I'm not sure why it just seems to die without logging the output.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong in the snippet above. Can you create a small reproducer on GitHub and share on the Vert.x or Quarkus user group?